# Acer Aspire 5750 wifi option missing after Windows-7 SP1 update

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, laptop, acer-aspire

I have an Acer Aspire 5750 laptop (32 bit). I updated the Service Pack (SP1) which I downloaded from the Microsoft [**website**](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5842).

The SP1 (`windows6.1-KB976932-X86.exe`) was updated successfully but after the update the wifi symbol (signal bars) is missing. Now there is no option to search for wifi networks. The internet can still be accessed using LAN cable connection.

I have already tried to download and install the Acer wifi driver from the Acer's official [**website**](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/support-product/3474?b=1). But wifi network is still not there even after that.

**UPDATE:** I checked and found that the update of SP1 had deleted the wireless adapter. I have installed the proper wireless adapter Acer website ***but still wifi is not working***. I can see the wifi adapter in `View Network connections`. It is already enabled. But my laptop is not looking for any network.

[image]

Comment: When you go to Network Connections, is your wifi adapter listed there? And if so, is it enabled?

Comment: no, wifi adapter is not listed there

Comment: Is there a little sliding switch on the front or side of your laptop for turning wifi on and off? Some of them are pretty small and hard to notice unless you look closely.

Comment: No, there is no switch. That was the first thing that I checked. There is something with the wifi driver or something. There are several such questions on the Internet but sadly none of them worked for me so far.

Comment: If you go into device manager, is there anything listed under Network Adapters?  If so do any of them have any symbols on the icon such as a red X, a yellow exclamation mark, or a down arrow etc...? You can access device manager by right clicking on Computer in the start menu and selecting Manage.  you can also search for device manager in the start menu search box.

Comment: wifi adapter is there. Please have a look at the screenshot that i have updated now.

Comment: From your screen shot it shows that "connections are available" which means it should be seeing WiFi networks.  What happens when you attempt to connect one? Any error messages?

Comment: just now it worked after couple of restarts and enabling/disabling the wifi network adapter in the device manager.

Comment: Cool.  What a weird problem!  You should write what you did to fix it as an answer and accept it. This way if any one else a similar problem your steps might be able to help.

Comment: Sure, I will do that :)